# Which design pattern to use for a "recent activity"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, design-patterns

I got a dashboard in my application, on which I want to have a 'recent activity'.

This info can come from all over the application (for example the following models: Timesheet, Expense, Invoice, ...).

Upon calling the dashboard screen I need to get info from all those models.  I will call them with a parameter (for example: last 24h, or last week, etc...) and each model should send it's data.

Is there an applicable design pattern that would be wise to use here?  (I have a dashboard model as well).

Comment: you can use https://github.com/chaps-io/public_activity . The pattern you are looking for is probably observer pattern.

Comment: Don't *look* for design patterns, *find* them. I'm not even sure what you're looking for here; the "best" answer will depend on what kind of data you need across the models, how normalized that data is, etc. You might want a mixin that spits out the data in a normalized format for however you're consuming it.

Comment: @DaveNewton all models will supply the data in the same format: a datetime, a user_id and a text...

Comment: @ArupRakshit ok thanks, will check out that gem.  I'm always amazed that for everything you want to do in rails, someone created a gem :-)

Comment: @rept haha,, they are good .. that's why. :)

Comment: @rept Then it's either a simple mixin, a gem, or keep a history log that everything writes to in addition to its normal job. The "best" solution still depends on what your actual requirements are, whether or not the *source* data is regular, etc.